# How many bytes does an stateless class have?

Tags: java, methods, singleton

If I have this classes:

```
public interface IBinaryCalculator{
double addition(double numb1, double numb2);
}

public class BinaryCalculator implements IBinaryCalculator{
 double addition(double numb1, double numb2){
  return numb1+numb2;  

}
}
```

Ok, the method should be static, but hey I have an interface over here. IS singleton the only answer and just have on class for a BinaryCalc? Lets say I build 10, 000 BinaryCalculator, it just have methods, does it have impact on performance, or should I use singleton.

Comment: An class's memory footprint is JVM dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be entirely sure, but it appears that you are worrying too much about the performance issues related to the creation of many instances of a given object.

IMHO you should worry about the design first, and later on you can worry about performance if such things get to be an issue. Honestly, your class does not look like the kind of class for which you will have a million objects swimming in the heap.

Your interface is what is called a SAM Type (single abstract method). And there are plenty of examples of them in the JDK itself. For instance java.util.Comparator and java.lang.Comparable are two good examples.

If you define your method as static, it must be based on your design and not on the functionality or the simplicity of the task that it does. You may know your design better than anyone else and the developers of this forum can help you with good ideas or challenge your current ones which could be helpful to improve what you already have.

The singlenton pattern that you mention has the intention to prevent the creation of more than a predefined number of instances of an given class, most typically they restrict it to one single instance. It is not evident in your design why you would like to do such thing, but worries about performance related to the number of instances does not sound like the best reason here.

In looking ways to simplify your design you may like to use inline anonymous inner classes, instead of providing a class implementation of your interface, if you are planning to have different types of calculator, perhaps having a [static factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) class where you can put all your SAM type implementations:

```
public class Calculators {

    public static BinaryCalculator getBasicCalculator(){
        return new BinaryCalculator() {

            @Override
            public double addition(double numb1, double numb2) {
                return numb1 + numb2;
            }
        };
    }

    public static BinaryCalculator getSofisticatedCalculator(){
        return new BinaryCalculator() {

            @Override
            public double addition(double numb1, double numb2) {
                //do any other sofisticated calculation
                return numb1 + numb2;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Then you could simply do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinaryCalculator simple = Calculators.getBasicCalculator();
    BinaryCalculator complex = Calculators.getSofisticatedCalculator();

    double result;
    result = simple.addition(10,11);
    result = complex.addition(10,11);
}
```

Also, if you are allowed to experiment, you may like to give it a try to the [JDK 8 Lambda Preview](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) where you could write the implementation of your calculator as a lamdba expression somewhat like this.

```
BinaryCalculator simple = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;
```

Or even inline in a method, for example

```
public class Pair {
        private final double a;
        private final double b;

        public Pair(double a, double b){
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public double calculateWith(BinaryCalculator calculator){
            return calculator.addition(a,b);
        }
    }
```

Then you could simple provide an lambda implementation for your SAM type like this:

```
Pair p = new Pair(10,11);
double result = p.calculateWith( (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2 );
System.out.println(result);
```

Of course, this is just a preview of the JDK 8, but hey, if you are allowed to experiment with the latest features, that'd be a really cool solution :-)

Comment: The purpose of this question is the use of Generic Repository, I'll use the repository in the domain, but i dont want to do for example. public Save (){
         Repository<Person> rper = new JPARepository<Person>();
         rper.save(this);
         }

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in this particular class that can't be "static".

The moment one class instance might have different state data than another, then you'll need individual objects.

"Singleton" is one thing (pardon the pun ;-)).

"Static" is something else.

And scalability is yet another separate issue.

Bottom line: if you need something to be an object, then make it an object.  If a method will never  need to reference instance data - by all means.  Knock yourself out and make it a static method, if you'd like,.

IMHO...

Comment: Im agree with the static approach, but I cannot make this method static because it is overriding it. I need to know these because in the repository patter, I have the same case. The repository is build every time the app needs some entity from db.

Answer (score 0):

Several questions, several answers.

1. I'm not sure how much memory an object without state occupies, but it needs some, as it has a monitor associated with it.
2. For classes of this type, you can either use a static approach, like java.lang.Math, or a normal instance based approach.
3. Singleton is increasingly considered bad style and should be used with caution. In the case of a stateless class it might be ok, but personally, I'd prefer just relying on users to not create useless objects.

Comment: May I ask you to support with some reference the bold affirmation that "singletons are increasingly considered bad style". The Singleton is a pattern, just like many other, with a context in which it is useful and with a set of advantages and drawbacks, and as such I am very curious to read any material supporting the allegation that they are a bad idea without highlighting any specific drawbacks of the given context.

Comment: There certainly can't be a single reference for a bold allegation like that, as this is something that at best comes from anecdotes. I would have liked to point you here: hhttps://code.google.com/p/testability-explorer/. They used to have a proper website where they discussed some of the issues, including the use of static variables, including the singleton pattern. Unfortunately, the links don't work anymore (or tonight, or whatever). The other part is harder to link, but pay attention to the comments you get on SO when people discuss using the singleton pattern and static stuff.

Comment: Now that was a long answer. The short answer is, there is a context when singleton is indeed justified. But often it is used when it is not justified. And I was certainly alleging that in the above case it is not justified. Even though it would not do any harm, either.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' do:

```
10,000  new BinaryCalculator().addition(42,24);
```

Do:

```
BinaryCalculator bc = new BinaryCalculator();
10,000  bc.addition(42,24);
```

If you use:

```
MemoryMXBean mBean = ManagementFactoryHelper.getMemoryMXBean();
mBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()
```

In an isolated test, you should see getUsed() growing and shrinking in the 1st example, and a stable usage in the 2nd. You could also use getUsed() to get a feel for how fast the heap is used up and GC'd.

Answer (score 0):

The memory used by a single instance of a class depends on the JVM you are using, and in some cases on other things.  But an object's headers *typically* occupy between 8 and 16 bytes.  Depending on that has been done to the object, there can be other hidden state as well; e.g.

- an "inflated" lock data structure,
- storage for the object's identity hashcode value.

But the chances are that this has no measurable bearing on the performance of your application.